# Ember App Kit: Set Resolver outside of Ember.Application.create()

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

To keep it short:

Is it possible to set up the `Resolver` of the application outside of the `Ember.Application.create()` block?

Ideally, I would like to set the `Resolver` in a `Ember.Application.initializer#initialize()` function. Something like:

```
import CustomResolver from 'appkit/utils/resolver/custom';
import CustomAjax from 'appkit/utils/ajax/custom';

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'resolver_setup',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
     // NOTE: For an unknown reason (unknown to me!) I can't import CustomAjax in CustomResolver...
     application.set('Resolver', CustomResolver.create({ajax: CustomAjax.create({})});
  }
});
```

Is this possible?

P.S.: The reason why I need a custom resolver is, that I'm fetching all templates from the server instead of delivering them to the user on application start. Therefore I'm extending the `ember-jj-abrams-resolver` which is used by default within EAK...

Comment: interesting approach - what is the business reason / advantage of delivering templates like this?

Comment: @ToranBillups the business reason / advantage of this form of template delivery is, that an application which consists of several hundreds of templates and with internationalization for several languages doesn't need to load all of the precompiled templates on start as most of them are not needed :)

Comment: That sounds like something the community could use a blog post on -any chance you could put something together? even a simple gist would be a great start that others could build off

Comment: I'll see what I can fiddle together and post the blog url as soon as possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think *initializers* can help you to set a custom Resolver, [according to the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L250), `container` is been set earlier than any initializers, resolver is a property of container.

You set the `Resolver` property inside initializer, but this will not be used by the process of set up the container. I think the right way is to reopen the `Ember.Application` and set the `Resolver` before create the `Ember.Application`.

```js
Ember.Application.reopenClass({
  Resolver: YOUR_CUSTOM_RESOLVER_NAME
});

Ember.Application.create({...});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - I completely forgot about this open issue as I solved it in a manner close to what you suggested. as I'm using `ember-app-kit` I was able to extend the `ember-jj-abrams-resolver` `import`ed it in the `app.js` file and set it directly as Resolver within `Ember.Application.create({Resolver: CustomResolver})`. I'll accept your answer as it's clearly possible to do it like you suggested :)